# Create a matrix with repetitive values from a slice of another matrix

Tags: julia

Suppose I have this matrix:

```
julia> mat=[1 2 3;4 5 6]
2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
```

Now I want to achieve something like this using a standard function:

```
4×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
```

Note that the important thing to me is using the slice! here the slice is `mat[1, :]`. I tried:

```
julia> fill(mat[1, :], 4,3)
4×3 Matrix{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3]
 [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3]
 [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3]
 [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3]

julia> repeat(mat[1, :], inner=(4,1))
9×1 Matrix{Int64}:
 1
 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
 2
 2
 3
 3
 3
 3
```

Comment: [Can I answer my question? Yes.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: While your question does have a clear answer, it is very unusual to need repeating rows (or columns) in a matrix. Each row does not contain any new information here. What do you need this for? Most likely you can achieve the same thing without duplicating data.

Comment: @DNF, Hi! Your question is excellent. Suppose you want to calculate the euclidean distance between a sample (with four columns) with 2000 other samples of the same size. One way is to use a for loop to calculate the dist between the sample and each other sample. But if you repeat that single sample 2000 times, you can take advantage of vectorized calculations! I can explain more if you ask. 

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what I was thinking of. You do not need to repeat the sample in this case, just use broadcasting instead. You can write `mat[1:1, :] .- mat2`, and the compiler will 'virtually' duplicate the single sample, without allocating the extra memory.

Comment: @DNF, are you sure that *" the compiler will 'virtually' duplicate the single sample"*? Isn't there any difference in speed?

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to phrase it that makes it clear, but yes, in a way that is what happens. You can read about it here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting It specifically addresses your use case. BTW, this also works in other languages like Matlab and numpy. And yes, there is a difference in speed, _not_ replicating is much faster, at least not slower.

Comment: @DNF, I already knew about broadcasting, But I thought maybe it isn't as efficient as using something like `mat1 - mat2` (without any broadcasting function). These need benchmarking, I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249392/discussion-between-dnf-and-shayan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or in this case just:

```
julia> repeat(mat[1:1, :], 4)
4×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
```

(note `1:1` to avoid transposition)

Comment: Thanks, professor  You always surprise Julia learners by proposing new ways!

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to find a workaround for this problem, and after reading the `repeat`'s documentation, I found my way:

```
julia> repeat(mat[1, :]', inner=(4,1))
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
```

The point was the `mat[1, :]` returns a Vector. Then applying `repeat` on it wouldn't lead to the expected output. Then transposing the vector is crucial in this case.